# How to use text from a TextBox as a file name?

Tags: c#, variables, text, textbox, concatenation

I am a beginner when it comes to c#.
Can anyone help me?

I want the variable **Username** to be used as the filename like .txt.
I have this code:

```
String Username = Nametxt.Text;
StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(@"*Username*.txt");
```

I want the value of *Username* to be used in (@"*Username*.txt"), i.e, *Username* should be replaced with the actual value of **Username**.

I'd be glad if anyone can help :)

Comment: `new StreamWriter("@" + Username + ".txt");`

Comment: ++++ Thank you :) Am new here but am sure I gonna get great help.

Comment: It's unclear to me where you're actually trying to get the username from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your issue.  You simply concatenate the variables in order to open up the correct file in your StreamWriter.

```
StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(Username + ".txt");
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the username and the file extension like this:

```
StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(Username + ".txt");
```

Or, you can use `String.Format` like this:

```
StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(String.Format("{0}.txt", Username));
```